# adding specific rows from datatable to datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a datatable which contains 1000's of rows , now I want to add a range of rows between first first index and last index from this datatable to my data grid view. How do I accomplish this ?

The datatable also contains the information about columns which I always want to maintain in the datagridview.

PS:
First Index and Last Index are some integer variables.
This is in c# using .net platform.

Comment: can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use rows 100 to 200 as DataSource, you can use `Enumerable.Skip/Take`:

```
datagridView1.DataSource = table.AsEnumerable()
                                .Skip(100)
                                .Take(100)
                                .CopyToDatatable();
```

From startIndex to endIndex with `Enumerable.Where`:

```
datagridView1.DataSource =  table.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where((r, i) => i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex)
                                 .CopyToDatatable();
```

Remember to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter on your data to limit the results shown in your `DataGridView`. Do some thing like

```
DataTable tmpDt = GetDataTable();
BindingSource source2 = new BindingSource();
source2.DataSource = tmpDt;
source2.Filter = "columnValue < 100 AND columnValue > 200";
dataGridView2.DataSource = source2;
```

The advantage of this approach is that the filter does not destroy your underlying data. You cahnge the `Filter` you can update the data displayed in the `DataGridView`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Googling given me following ready to use articles,

How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DataRow[] rw = myDataTable.Select("#" + firstindex+ "# >= FirstIndexCol 
                                     AND SecondIndexCol <= #" + SecondIndex+ "#");
```